# Can we use OkHttp lib in Java embedded ME environment?

Tags: java, embedded, okhttp, http2

I like to know if IoT Development Platform of Qualcomm supports OkHttp, which runs in Java Embedded ME. If it does't support Okhttp, kindly suggest any other lib that support Http/2 in Java Embedded ME platform.